# Make iOS Simulator automatically open up with the keyboard displayed?

Tags: swift, keyboard, ios-simulator

(e.g., in a UITextField in Safari)

So when I click the "Run" triangle in Xcode it will automatically show me the keyboard in the iOS simulator when it pops up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewWillAppear` method of the initial view controller call:

```
yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

This should make your text field the first responder and should show the keyboard.

If, however, your text field becomes focused and you see cursor but keyboard is not visible press Cmd + K. In simulator you have to sometimes manually call the keyboard to appear. This shouldn't be a concern - when you test on your iPhone everything will work fine and keyboard will show as long as your text field is first responder